# Eclipse WindowBuilder / Jframe - Update labels text

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe, refresh, windowbuilder

Hi im working on a program that will run through a list of programs and open them.
in order for this to look nice i need to change the text in a label to match the programs name. how ever when i call the ChnageTitle and Refresh funtions they do not appear to work. can you please help point out where i am going wrong?

here is the main auto generated window builder code i edited it slightly and added

```
    package WindowBuilder;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import Logic.ButtonPresses;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class WindowBuilder {
    public JLabel Title;
    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public void Launch() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    WindowBuilder window = new WindowBuilder();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public WindowBuilder() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    public void Refresh(){
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }
    public void ChangeTitle(){
        Title.setText("Test");
    }
    public void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next");
        btnNext.setBounds(365, 226, 79, 45);
        btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                ButtonPresses.Next();
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNext);

        JButton btnBack = new JButton("Back");
        btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ButtonPresses.Back();
            }
        });
        btnBack.setBounds(0, 226, 79, 45);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnBack);

        Title = new JLabel("Program Name");
        Title.setBounds(9, 11, 89, 33);
        frame.getContentPane().add(Title);

        JButton btnInstall = new JButton("Install/Run");
        btnInstall.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnInstall.setBounds(173, 226, 116, 45);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnInstall);
    }

}
```

here is where i am calling the functions.

```
    package Main;

import Logic.ProgramAdder;
import Logic.Programs;
import WindowBuilder.WindowBuilder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main start = new Main();
        start.Start();
    }
    public void Start(){
        WindowBuilder wb = new WindowBuilder();
        wb.Launch();
        ProgramAdder.ProgramList();
        DisplayPrograms();
        wb.ChangeTitle();
        wb.Refresh();
    }
    public static void DisplayPrograms(){
        for (Programs p : ProgramAdder.programs) {
               System.out.print(p.ProgramName);
               System.out.println(p.ProgramPath);
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Method names should NOT start with an upper case character. Follow [Java conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Don't use a null layout and setBounds(,,,). Swing was designed to be used with [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: The code was generated automatically by window builder. So im not sure how i can go about changing this without it messing up. and ive always liked using capitals for every word its just my personal preference.

Comment: The problem is you are posting code on the forum asking for help. Your naming conventions cause problems for the forum highlighting which makes it difficult for us to read your code. Either get rid of the IDE (its better to code the GUI yourself) or learn how to configure the IDE to follow Java conventions.

Comment: ahh ok sorry i was not aware the website would have difficulties ill keep that in mind next time im posting.By code the gui my self does that mean not using the window builder interface and instead coding in the buttons ect directly? im quite new to gui coding in java im used to visual basic.

Comment: Start with working demo code from the Swing tutorial. For example [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html). The code there will show you how to structure a class and the code is not dependent on code generated from an IDE which means your code will be portable as you move from IDE to IDE. Just use the IDE to format the code, debug and so on.

Comment: Thanks i probably should have done more initial research on java gui's i just downloaded the first thing i found. sorry if i came across as rude in my first comment. ill have a read and start from the beginning and hopefully that will solve the problems i am having

Answer (score 0):

I have recetly developed a simple GUI in Swing to run python scripts from it. 
Had this same problem (On JFrame, a Label was supposed to tell the user when python script was being executed), try:

To show the label:

```
    Label.setVisible(true);
    Label.paintImmediately(x, y, width, height);
```

To hide the label:

```
    Label.setVisible(false);
```

**UPDATE:**

Change text using this while label is invisible.

```
    Label.setText(String text);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply im actually leaving the shop for today but i will give it a shot tommorw

Comment: Hi i got a chance to test it out just now and it still does not appear to change the text. could it have something to do with me calling it from a separate class?

Comment: Of course this does not change the text. This is to make the label visible or invisible. (You can change the text with "Label.setText(String text);" When the label is not visible.

Comment: So you can only change text while the label is not visable?

Comment: I can´t confirm that right now, but for sure is the easiest way, simply make it invisible, change it, and make it visible again. This way you avoid possible alignment (or any other kind of) errors